# Three.js CanvasRenderer issues

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm just trying out Three.js. As I want to use CanvasRenderer as a fallback for devices where WebGL is not supported, I've noticed two issues:

### Distored line / Bad geometry?

[image]

### Additional pixel

[image]

Here's my current code

```js
var width = 960;
var height = 500;
var aspect = width / height;

var D = 1;

var CanvasRenderer = true;

var scene    = new THREE.Scene();
var camera   = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(-D * aspect, D * aspect, D, -D, 1, 1000);

if(CanvasRenderer) {
    var renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer({
        alpha: true,
        antialias: true
    });
} else {
     var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
 alpha: true,
      antialias: true
     });
}

renderer.setSize(width, height);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(0.1, 1, 0.5);


var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, [
 new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        color: 0x222222, // right
        overdraw: true
    }),
 new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        color: 0xffffff,
        overdraw: true
    }),
    new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        color: 0xEDE6F5, // Top
        overdraw: true
    }),
    new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        color: 0xffffff,
        overdraw: true
    }),
    new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        color: 0xFFFFFF, // Left
        overdraw: true
    }),
    new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        color: 0xffffff,
        overdraw: true
    })
]);

scene.add(cube);
scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0xFFFFFF));

camera.position.set(20, 20, 20);
camera.lookAt(scene.position);

renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #EEE;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/js/renderers/Projector.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/js/renderers/CanvasRenderer.js"></script>
```

### WebGL difference

You can see the difference with WebGL renderer:

[image]

### JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/4tbs4tpL/2/

Comment: "I want to use CanvasRenderer as a fallback for devices where WebGL is not supported". If you are doing non-trivial things this is generally not an easy route to take. It's not impossible, but you can expect a lot more pitfalls like this one. Set your expectations accordingly :)

Answer (score 1):

When using `CanvasRenderer`, the `Material.overdraw` property takes values between 0 and 1. A reasonable value is 0.5.

The artifacts you refer to will likely diminish with lower values of `overdraw`.

three.js r.86

Comment: When setting overdraw to 0.5, we can see some kind of wireframe line and I need to avoid that.

Comment: I have explained to you the cause of your artifacts. `CanvasRenderer` is limited. Find the best compromise. Try changing your background color.